# Android Fragment Transaction .replace wrong 2nd arguement

Tags: java, android

I keep getting a wrong second argument type error on this code @ the ft.replace(..., fragment).  I'm not sure what's wrong and would appreciate any help.

```
package valdes.listone;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GroceryListFragment.GroceryListListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public void itemClicked(long id){
    //GroceryListListener
    GroceryDetailFragment fragment = new GroceryDetailFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragment.setListId(id);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment); //error is here.
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you plz add your Logcat for more reference

Comment: Is your GroceryDetailFragment class extends Fragment Class?

Comment: Make sure GroceryDetailFragment  and FragmentTransaction has same import either android.support.v4.app or android.app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in your `GroceryDetailFragment` Fragment. And you are using `getFragmentManager()` that returns a `FragmentManager` which supports `android.app.Fragment` class.

To get your code working extend `android.app.Fragment` in your `GroceryDetailFragment` class OR use `getSupportFragmentManager()` method which supports android.support.v4.app.Fragment and you are good to go.

**android.supportv4.app.Fragment** class is used to support android version prior to `android 3.0`.

To know more about fragment read this link [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.